# Requested URL not found (FuelPHP)

Tags: php, apache, fuelphp

For the first time, I tried uploading a segment of my code to the web to test.

http://cps.deremoe.com

It managed to load the primary page, but when I clicked the register button I get

```
The requested URL /account/register was not found on this server.
```

Of course on my development machine it works fine. So I might be missing something. I have a wordpress install on the server and it works fine.

Here is my vhost settings for the account.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/cps.deremoe.com/public"
    ServerName cps.deremoe.com
    <Directory "/www/cps.deremoe.com">
        Satisfy Any
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: check your mod_rewrite to be enabled

Comment: indeed the most likely suspect. If your config doesn't allow the .htaccess to be processed. Does "http://cps.deremoe.com/index.php?account/register" work? If so, your install is ok, and it's definitely a rewrite issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your vhost to

```
<Directory "/www/cps.deremoe.com/public">
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After verify into /www/cps.deremoe.com/public if the .htaccess file exists.